# removing strings or characters from variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do i go about removing  "#" and "@" from the  variable using jquery ?

```
example  var  inputval ="#111-111-1111"  or "@some@email.com"

 var inputval =$(this).siblings("input[type=text]").val();
   alert("inputval " +inputval);
   $("#some-text").focusEnd();

   ///$("#some-text").append('a'+inputval+'a');


   $('#some-text').val($('#some-text').val()+'  ' + inputval);
```

Thanks

Comment: You can use a regular expression. Are you only interested in removing `#` and `@` from the beginning of a string?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no need to use jQuery to accomplish this task, straight JavaScript will do:

```
inputval = inputval.replace(/[#@]/g, "");
```

Comment: +1 - you might mention that this is straight JavaScript with no need for jQuery

Comment: you are too fast man. :) while I was fiddling with jsfiddle your answer was up. well done.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this

```
var inputval = inputval.replace(/[#@]+/g, "");
```

here is jsfiddle code

http://jsfiddle.net/RYatN/